# derive new column with pandas assign based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to derive a new variable in pandas data frame based on a condition using assign().

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'flag': ['y', 'n', 'y', 'y']})

df.assign(
    flag_n = lambda x: True if x['flag'] == 'y' else False
)
```

I get the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any ideas how to do this. It is important to be using assign if possible

Regards

Comment: df.assign(
    flag_n = df['flag']=='y'
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) as well:

```
df.assign(flag_n = df.flag.map({'y': True, 'n': False}))
```

Comment: is there a way using this syntax to get all others strings into one value ?

Comment: do you mean just pass it `y` and all other values will be coerced to `False`?

Answer (score 5):

When you're doing `if x['flag'] == 'y'`, you are not indexing on any particular row, so the result will be an entire Series of *booleans*:

```
print(x['flag'] == 'y')

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: flag, dtype: bool
```

And so of course, the error is suggesting you to perform some reduction operation over this Series, as it contains multiple results from the applied condition.

---

Also note, that this result is precisely what you're trying to obtain. Any comparison operation will be returning either `True` or `False`, so adding `True if ... else False` is superfluous.

So what you need is simply:

```
df.assign(flag_n = df['flag'] == 'y')
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
df.assign(flag_n=lambda x: x['flag'] == 'y')
```